# Pyinstaller with Anaconda 3 and Python 3.7 not working?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

I freshly installed Anaconda3 2019.10. Than installed some Python Libraries into it, which are requests, BeautifulSoup, PyInstaller.

So the Base Environment from PyInstaller contains Python 3.7.4. As you can see from here:

```
(base) C:\>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I had problems with Pyinstaller using a Specfile.
So I tried to strip it down to a minimal demonstration and I found that even with the simplest Python script, I cannot build my Exe:

Running:

```
pyinstaller ibGetRuntimes.py --onefile
```

ibGetRuntimes.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = 1*1
```

This simple script obviously runs fun when I do `python ibGetRuntimes.py`.
But when using Pyinstaller, this error pops up:

[image]

As it is a completely fresh Anaconda installation with freshly installed Pyinstaller, I'm struggling to find out the root cause. Couldnt't either find a solution via Google.

Do you have any ideas?

**EDIT**
Pyinstaller under my Python 2 environment which I created as well works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install requests, BeautifulSoup, PyInstaller?  Because requests and beautifulsoup are **already** included in Anaconda.

Comment: `conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4`, `conda install requests`. So probably was just an update than

Comment: Also, did you do as suggested in the error message and run `pyinstaller --clean`?

Comment: Yes, but it should be clean because everything was freshly installed and I deleted the dist/build directories where pyinstaller stores intermediate files. Btw... Pyinstaller under my Python 2 environment which I created as well works fine.

Comment: Did you use PIP or Conda to install pyinstaller?

Comment: `conda install pyinstaller`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206347/discussion-between-james-and-tim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use PIP to uninstall the Pyinstaller from your root environment if you installed it with PIP.  PIP packages and Conda environments don't always play nice.  They are improving this with every release of Conda, but it can still cause issues.

Next, try creating a new Conda environment specifically for Pyinstaller.  The latest release on Pyinstaller is on conda-forge.  Then switch to that environment and try again.

```
conda create -n pyexe requests beautifulsoup pyinstaller=3.6 -c defaults -c conda-forge
conda activate pyexe
pyinstaller ibGetRuntimes.py --onefile
```

This worked for me on the a very similar setup as your own.

Comment: Thanks, creating a new env with directly giving the packages required seems to have worked :o